# Transparent background in WebView - empty content

Tags: android, webview, transparent

I have a problem trying to set WebView background to transparent in my application. I found a lot of similar questions and workarounds how to set WebView background to transparent.
The most popular solution for API > 11 is:

```
// Color.TRANSPARENT or 0x00000000 or simple 0 as a value
webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
   setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

However when I add this line to setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null) my HTML content in the webview just disappear. Webview itself has correct scale (height of content), scroll and even reacting on click or tap on it (I have image-zoom system on tap). But the content is not showing.

If I remove setLayerType() method content shows fine but it flickering on scroll.

I use Android 4.2.2 JB (API 17) and hardwareAcceleration for whole application is set to true. My HTML-content body CSS set to

```
background:transparent;
```

Also, my WebView placed inside Relative view with 2 other TextView and the RelativeLayout itselft placed inside ScrollView.

I have not found any solution for my case - all advises I found are to setLayerType() to software.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the problem is that my webview was inside of scrollview:

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="@string/alert.resume"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then, I removed the scrollview and the trick works!

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="@string/alert.resume"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Trick as usual:

```
WebView text = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    text.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    WebSettings settings = text.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    text.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) // Android v3.0+
            try {
            text.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
```